# Named field with Umlaut not recognized with Cassava

Tags: csv, haskell

I'm trying to parse a CSV file containing German text, i.e., it is not "comma" separated, but semicolon separated and it may contain Umlauts (äöü etc).

Using [Cassava](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.5.2.0) and following the linked [tutorial](https://www.stackbuilders.com/tutorials/haskell/csv-encoding-decoding/), for a column with a header including an Umlaut, I'm getting the error:

> parse error (Failed reading: conversion error: no field named "W\228hrung") at "\nEUR;0,99"

MRE:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Char
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as ByteString
import Data.Csv
import Data.Text

myOpts = defaultDecodeOptions {
      decDelimiter = fromIntegral (ord ';')
  }

data Transaction = Tx
  { waehrung :: Text
  , betrag :: Text
  } deriving Show

instance FromNamedRecord Transaction where
  parseNamedRecord m =
    Tx
      <$> m .: "Währung"
      <*> m .: "Betrag"

main :: IO ()
main =
  ByteString.readFile "bank.csv"
    >>= print . decodeByNameWith @Transaction myOpts
```

Save this as `bank.csv`:

```
Währung;Betrag
EUR;14,12
EUR;0,99
```

Versions:
GHC 8.10.7
cassava ^>=0.5.2.0

Comment: Where is the type `Betrag` defined?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to remove that for the minimal repro. Fixed the gist to just `Text`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write:

```
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as Text
instance FromNamedRecord Transaction where
  parseNamedRecord m =
    Tx
      <$> m .: Text.encodeUtf8 "Währung"
      <*> m .: "Betrag"
```

The problem is that `cassava` is internally representing field names as the `ByteString` of the UTF-8 encoding of the text.  However, the `IsString` instance for `ByteString`s which is used to encode a string literal to a `ByteString` does *not* use UTF-8 encoding but rather encodes each character as the least-significant byte of its code point (which is basically *never* what you want for non-ASCII strings).

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! I had a hunch that the encoding of the ByteString was at fault, but I couldn't find out what the default encoding for ByteStrings is. This behavior, however, is very strange indeed :/